# How to insert IDOrder into OrderDetaill at the same time

Tags: java, mysql

I have two tables

- `OrderTable(id_OrderTable, id_OrderDetaill)`
- `OrderDetaill(id_OrderTable, id_product, number, price)`

`id_OrderTable` has int type, and auto-increment

How can I insert one record of OrderTable then get the id_OrderTable from just the added record to add OrderDetaill
I'm trying to created one invoice which contain bulk of item.
Please help me in this case,
Thanks

Comment: `id_OrderDetaill` are is primary key for any table ?

Comment: No, it's not, id_OrderDetaill is not primary key for any table